# I'm getting this error: Unknown error (0x80005000)

Tags: .net, iis, active-directory, ldap

First of all, let me tell you that my code works fine during the day, but each morning when the user tries to connect, the following error is thrown:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unknown error (0x80005000)

Yes I'm using LDAP, what is funny is that everything works fine until next day. Restarting the application in iis solves the problem, but I have to do this every day so how can I fix this issue? 
I'm thinking that maybe this issue is in the iis, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I don't have a fix but can tell you we are experiencing the same problem. 1st occurrence was ~Dec 11th 2018. Then started happening almost daily Jan 11, 2019.
Coincidently these dates are right after our server OS patch window. I've tried scheduling auto-recycle of appPool for 3:55am but this morning it failed again. Our server admin has been manually recycling after failure to clear up the problem for the day. May or may not be related but we are running this application pool under a Managed Service Account. Are you?

Comment: Yes I am! Some updates on my question are: it doesn't necessary happen at morning and not all the days, we haven't had that issue recently but still happens.

Comment: we got this as well, server 2016 IIS7, randomly gets this error. Only common factor we could find was it happened after server patching. app pool recycle fixed it, so I'm assuming it happened when an update broke something important.